# Hover effect in style doesn't work (ToolBarPanel) - WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface

I have a toolbarpanel which I've made a custom style.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="toolbar_opciones" TargetType="{x:Type ToolBarPanel}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="DeepSkyBlue"/> <!-- does not work -->
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"  Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="CadetBlue"/>
            </Trigger> <!-- does not work -->
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<ToolBarPanel Style="{StaticResource toolbar_opciones}"/>
```

The cursor works but the background property no, why?

Comment: does the `background` property change when the mouse hover over the element?

Comment: also make sure that you are not override the background property in the C# code

Comment: When the mouse hover over the element doesn't change and I didn't write any c# code, so the background property isn't override.

Comment: Can u just try another value for the background property. For example try black

Comment: Why changing the color can solve the issue?

Comment: Will not solve. I just wanted to make sure that we notice the difference if it apply.

Comment: I was afraid of case that the code is working but the color is not very noticeable

Comment: Any way I will try your code tomorrow mornning on my pc. Good night

Comment: The cited code does actually work on a clean project with .NET 4.0 and later, so probably the problem is outside of this code.

Comment: This it can be the problem, because I use 4.5 framework and to do many things I had to search 2 versions of the se code. How can it be the code for net framework 4.0 or later?

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code, and here is the fix

```
<ToolBarPanel Style="{StaticResource toolbar_opciones}"/>
```

look at it closely, you were missing the double quotation which close the `Style` attribute. When I added it to the `XAML`, the `Background` has been applied.

Cheers.

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I hve made an error typing the question. It can be that I'm using net framework 4.5?